# C++ native Vs C++/Cli Performance ( for OpenCV project)

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, opencv

We're developing a project that uses **OpenCV** library to track hand gestures and motion sensing. I'm confused whether to go for native c++ program or to use C++/CLI provided in .NET (VC++).

Performance is of utmost importance and heavy image processing is required. Since we're planning to use the OpenCV extensive methods and the project requires frequent communication with the OS.

Also, where can I find IPP library for accelerating the OpenCV application program?
Won't '.NET framework' hinder the performance of the project?

Also please suggest us the proper environment to work in. I've seen many OpenCV projects been done in VC++.

Should we go for VC++ ( Coz this option gives me an advantage to build a proper and appealing gui)?

Help!

Comment: What parts of .NET do you plan to use?

Comment: Very similar questions recently asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691198/selecting-an-appropriate-ide and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652327/choice-between-win32-apis-and-net-framework

Answer (score 2):

Only go down the C++/CLI route if you absolutely must use .NET features. There shouldn't be any differences in performance for your application, though c++/cli is a managed language.

Intel has a great IPP library you can use.

If you're already comfortable with VC++, go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Most performance problems arise from improper use of frameworks and badly written code. Both native C++ and Managed C++ (CLI) would work just fine for you. I'd prefer native C++ for easier integration with OpenCV (my personal opinion). As far as environment is concerned, I don't think you'll find anything better than Visual Studio.